# Self-join in PostgreSQL view

Tags: postgresql, view, self-join

I'm trying to create views that would accumulate all the needed data from joined sources:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dir AS
SELECT
    dir_data.id,
    dir_data.parent_id,
    dir_data.name,
    (owner.*)::owner, -- owner_id
FROM
    dir_data
    LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.id = dir_data.owner_id
```

For example, this allows to select owner's data in easy way:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    (owner).id AS owner_id,
    (owner).name AS owner_name,
    ((owner).company).name AS owner_company
FROM
    dir
WHERE
    id = 7
```

The problem is that I need to do a self-join with view `dir` (which is the vew being created) to convert `parent_id` field in similar way. PostgreSQL does not seem to like it, it says that `relation "dir" does not exist`.

Any hints?

---

Answer to Marcelo Cantos comment:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dir AS
SELECT
    ...
FROM
    dir_data
    LEFT JOIN owner ON owner.id = dir_data.owner_id -- "standard" join
    LEFT JOIN dir AS parent_dir ON parent_dir.id = dir_data.parent_id -- self-join, does not work
```

Comment: Can you show us the self-join?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a recursive view, but in the latest postgres you can make recursive queries: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

Comment: I know about recursive queries, have used them, but that's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Well, the answer is still there - "You can't create a recursive view".

Comment: I hate to bring an old question back from the dead but PostgreSQL 9.3 will allow creation of recursive views.

Comment: @Nik, It would be worse if you brought it up with bad news ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH    RECURSIVE dir AS
        (
        SELECT  dir_data.id,
                dir_data.parent_id,
                dir_data.name,
                owner
        FROM    dir_data
        LEFT JOIN
                owner
        ON      owner.id = dir_data.owner_id
        WHERE   dir_data.id = 7
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  dir_data.id,
                dir_data.parent_id,
                dir_data.name,
                owner
        FROM    dir
        JOIN    dir_data
        ON      dir_data.id = dir.parent_id
        LEFT JOIN
                owner
        ON      owner.id = dir_data.owner_id
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    dir
```